# Transferring data from IOS app to Watch App in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb, watchconnectivity

I created an app in which data is displayed on current View from previous View. The data includes an image and Three labels. Now in the current view i have a "send to watch" button which will also store the data to database and at the same time it will transfer the displayed data to watch. I am using FMDB database for storing data. How can i transfer data from IOS  app to watch app. Can anybody explain me step by step as i am new to IOS development. My current view of storyboard is below:
[my storyboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKM0a.png)

and when i run my app, its current page is below
[application running page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAbTU.png)

my source code for last view is below:

```
class TicketDetailViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

var databasePath = NSString()
var holding_Image: UIImage?
var hold_ticketName: String = ""
var hold_ticketDate: String = ""
var hold_ticketTime: String = ""
var session: WCSession!


@IBOutlet weak var ticket_grey: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var cropped_frame: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var display_image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ticket_type_name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ticket_date: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ticket_time: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if WCSession.isSupported(){
        self.session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        self.session.delegate = self
        self.session.activateSession()
    }

    display_image.image = holding_Image
    ticket_type_name.text = hold_ticketName
    ticket_date.text = hold_ticketDate
    ticket_time.text = hold_ticketTime

    let filemgr =  NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
    var ticketDB: FMDatabase

    databasePath = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("tickets.sqlite")

    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String)
    {

        ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if ticketDB.open()
        {

            let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TICKETS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMAGE TEXT, TICKET_TYPE TEXT, DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT)"
                    if !ticketDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                    {
                        print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                    }
                    ticketDB.close()
                    } else
                    {

                     print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                    }
        }

}
  @IBAction func sendToWatch(sender: UIButton) {

    let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    if ticketDB.open()
    {

        let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TICKETS (image, ticket_type, date, time) VALUES ('\(display_image.image!)','\(ticket_type_name.text!)', '\(ticket_date.text!)', '\(ticket_time.text!)')"

        let result = ticketDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

        if !result
        {

            print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

        } else
        {

            let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Success!", description: "Your data is saved to Database!", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

            alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in



            }))

            self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print(databasePath)

        }
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Please refer this link to understand flow between iphone to iwatch
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030296/watchkit-ios-sending-data-between-watch-and-iphone

Comment: hey krutharth..I only need to display data in watch. i dont need to send back to ios app...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024062/is-there-an-official-way-to-pass-data-between-apple-watch-and-iphone

Comment: I am not getting it..Can u send me in swift version not objective C

Comment: http://basememara.com/sharing-data-between-apple-watch-and-iphone-in-swift/

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Comment: no krutharth....still stucked

Comment: where you stucked.can you please tell?

Comment: hey krutharth, in the last page of my app i have 3 labels and 1 imageview displayed. Can u tell me how to fetch data from FMDB database so that it can fetch and then display it on my watch app?

Comment: are you using Sqlitemanager? and what is your query.

Comment: i am using SQLPro for SQLite

Comment: Ok.try to add data in database

Comment: data is being saved but if i want to display the current saved data to my apple watch from my ios app on button click, then it should be fetched right?.. So how to do it in my code?

Comment: it is requirement for you to use database?

Comment: its not requirement but atleast i need to use for saving data locally

Comment: or is there any other method for saving and fetching data

Comment: Yes.There is other method

Comment: then how can i apply in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can share data or submit that data using App Groups.
Go to target, tap on Capabilities there you can find "App Groups", just enable it and add a entry like "group.com.development.xyzapp" by which you can share data from iOS app to watch and vice versa. You can save data from iOS app by below code.

`- (void)sendDataToWatch 
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]    initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.development.xyzapp"];
    [userDefaults setObject:object forKey:@"itemone"];
    [userDefaults setObject:object forKey:@"itemtwo"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}`

Now you can get this data from you watch.

Hope this will help.

Comment: hello manish, appreciate for your answer i want to display same data in watch as it is displayed in my ios...Can you refer the screenshot that i have attached earlier in my question

Comment: `[userDefaults setObject:@"moviename" forKey:@"mymovie"];
 [userDefaults setObject:@"dateobject" forKey:@"moviedate"];
 [userDefaults setObject:@"ImageObject" forKey:@"moviepic"];
`
Now while you reload app watch list/screen you can get this all keys by all above keys.

Comment: hey manish i have put my source code for last view screenshot that i have uploaded earlier..Can u tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: now i want that the displayed data in my last view i.e ticket_title,date and time labels and image below that show display in watch where i have taken 3 labels and an imageView...So how can i do it by the code i have published